# Display the username who ran the build in Build History

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How can I display the username who executed the build next to the build number? like in the image below 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try entering `Started by ([\S]+)` in the section "Post-build Actions ->
Set build description -> Regular expression" of your job config.

Comment: Thanks but I want it to be displayed on that build history window, like without having to go to console log or any other page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add user name to build description.

```
currentBuild.description = currentBuild.getBuildCauses().shortDescription[0]
```

Then you will get something like bellow

```
* #1 Feb 24, 2020 10:00 AM
| Started by user max
```

If you want use user only then

```
currentBuild.description = currentBuild.getBuildCauses().userId[0]
```

Data structure is :

```
[{"_class":"hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause","shortDescription":"Started by user max","userId":"max","userName":"max"}]
```

Comment: thanks. but I want to display the username in this window on the main page of my job, not in the description of build.

Answer (score 0):

See, install and enable for the job
https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-user-vars-plugin/

Then change name of build using `BUILD_USER_ID` variable, like

```
#${BUILD_NUMBER}: ${GIT_REVISION,length=8} (${GIT_BRANCH}) by ${BUILD_USER_ID}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Groovy Postbuild and user build vars plugin
2. edit job configure，check 【Set jenkins user build variables】，then you can get env variables 'BUILD_USER'
3. Post-build Actions, add 【Groovy Postbuild】, Groovy Script change to

   manager.addShortText(manager.envVars['BUILD_USER'])

Answer (score 0):

**Install Build trigger Badge Plugin:**
[Jenkins Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/buildtriggerbadge/#:%7E:text=This%20plugin%20displays%20icon(s,shown%20in%20the%20build%20history.))